# Xamarin.Forms: deployment issue after Visual Studio upgrade

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

After upgrading Visual Studio Professional 2019 to version 16.9.2, when I try to deploy on Android Emulator
api 28 (9.0), I get following error:

`Error XA0130: Sorry. Fast deployment is only supported on devices running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. Please disable fast deployment in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true'.`

Before the upgrade, everything worked fine. This is really frustating!

Comment: Is the deploy setting on `Debug` or `Release`?

Comment: Is in debug mode

Comment: there seems to be no issues then...did you tried deleting obj & bin folders of complete solution & restart the visual studio, close all active instances?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I've same issue, VS Mac version 8.9.5 build 4 and Android version 7.0

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5794

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

To correct this problem I had to

1. uninstall app on Android phone (important step)
2. Unload Android Project from solution explorer
3. This brings up the project file code now search code for
   `<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>false</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>`
4. Change false to true save
5. reload project problem solved.

Note leave fast deploy checked.

Comment: I tried, but this automatically uncheck Use Fast Deployment after .csproj save.

Comment: Upvote because the solution for me in latest versions of VS is I need to edit csproj. For some reason with custom build configs you cant change the User Fast Deploy, it's greyed out, in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Go to >> Solution Properties>> Android Options>> Uncheck "Use Fast Deployment(debug mode only)"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently after adding images to my project found out that I had upper case letters as a name SomePicture.png renaming all images to lower case solved it.

Answer (score 0):

@AlwinBrabu, I think you meant "Project Properties" -> Android Options -> Uncheck Fast Deployment(debug mode only).

This worked for me, although this is a workaround.  I do not consider it a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I had to right-click on the Android project in the Solution Explorer, then in `Options` -> `Android Build` uncheck the `Fast Assembly Deployment` option.

Then deploy the project on the Android emulator.

But after deploying it once, I went back to the settings and checked (i.e. ticked) the Fast Assembly Deployment option, and subsequent deploys worked fine.

I'm running Visual Studio for Mac 2022 version 17.0.1 (build 72).