# There is a problem with reinstalling the Xamarin program on the phone if it has been uninstalled

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms

there was a problem with the application debugging. I used to debug it and everything was fine. Then I deleted the application from the phone, but now I need to use it again. But when deploying, I get an error:

`Error XA0130: Sorry. Fast deployment is only supported on devices running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. Please disable fast deployment in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true'. 0`,

all the options on the Internet do not work, can someone help, thanks. I am using Android version 9.0-API 28

The program has been uninstalled from the phone and now I need to use it again.

Comment: Did you do either of the things suggested by the error message?

Comment: There were no suggestions in the message, just an error line, I used this to fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799236/xamarin-forms-deployment-issue-after-visual-studio-upgrade

Comment: But it did not help me

Comment: "Please disable fast deployment ..." seems like a pretty clear suggestion.

Comment: When I Uncheck "Use Fast Deployment(debug mode only)" the program is not compiled, and simply knocked out.And not debug

Comment: try deleting bin & obj folder of project & restart visual studio.

Comment: Are you using a Custom Application in your project ?

Comment: "all the options on the Internet do not work" - Please *list* what you have tried. And did any of those attempts give a different error message?

Comment: What version of Android is on the phone?  Are you able to debug on an emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Under "Debugging options", make sure "Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)" is checked.

Verify that "Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only) is NOT checked.

Then `Rebuild Solution`. Should be able to debug again.

---

2. As mentioned in a comment, deleting bin and obj folders of your project(s) is even more thorough than "Clean Solution" or "Rebuild Solution. Should get your project to a clean state.

---

3. Power Off your phone. Then power it back on.

---

4. If powering off phone doesn't fix, then its possible that the Fast Deployment module was left behind when uninstalled app, and for some reason is not recognized when reinstall app.

Fix is to completely uninstall app manually using "adb" command line:

Visual Studio, Tools menu > Android > Run ADB Command Prompt

`adb uninstall com.example.yourApp`. Substitute your app's bundle name for "com.example.yourApp" - it should have a format like that, probably with your company's website as the first two parts.